# Why does using sum using get take so long?

Tags: laravel, sum, laravel-5.3, eloquent, bigdata

I have 10.000 items.
When I `sum()` without using `get()` like this:

```
$total_salary = Employee::where('year','=', '2017')
    ->sum('total_salary');

$total_bonus = Employee::where('year','=', '2017')
    ->sum('total_bonus');

return ['total_salary'=>$total_salary, 'total_bonus'=>$total_bonus];
```

It takes 6 seconds.

When I `sum()` with `get()` like this:

```
$query = Employee::where('year','=', '2017')
             ->get();

$data['total_salary'] = $query->sum('total_salary');
$data['total_bonus'] = $query->sum('total_bonus');

return $data;
```

It takes 20 seconds.
How can I use `sum()` with `get()` without waiting for such a long time?

Comment: you forgot to add `all()` before `where()` condition

Comment: @Advaith, I use https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry i mis understand your question.

### but the reason is the second one is doing sum with Collection library and it costs so much.

As you call sum after `get` function, you are doing sum with `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and thats why its take so much.

Lets sum it using database:

```
$result = Employee::where('year','=', '2017')
    ->select(
        \DB::raw('sum(total_salary) as total_salary'),
        \DB::raw('sum(total_bonus) as total_bonus')
    )
    ->get();

echo $result->total_salary;
echo $result->total_bonus;
```